# Finding eigen values of numpy array of arrays

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

So I have a 3 numpy arrays which has the following dimensions,

```py
a.shape = (704, 528)
b.shape = (704, 528)
c.shape = (704, 528)
```

And I have a square matrix that looks like this,

```py
mat = np.array([[a, b], [b, c]])
```

I need to find the eigen values of this. I'm aware that it's going to be a matrix of eigen values. But when I use `numpy.linalg.eig()`, it gives me an error: `numpy.linalg.LinAlgError: Last 2 dimensions of the array must be square`.

I haven't found many resources as to how to do this, could someone guide me to any sources or give me a solution? Thank you!

Comment: `mat` is (2,2,704,528) shape, right?  Be more specific about the expected eigenvalues.  `eig` clearly states that the array should be `(..., M, M)`.

Answer (score 0):

Eigenvalues are only defined for square matrices.

Your matrix has 2*704 = 1408 rows and 2*528 = 1056 columns, hence you get an error as `numpy.linalg.eig()` is expecting a square matrix as input.

Depending on your goal of wanting to compute eigenvalues, you might want to consider SVD which is defined for non-square matrix as well. You might also want to examine if the matrix that you constructed is indeed the matrix that you intend to construct.